# Searching Up the Scope vs Accessing the DOM - Speed Performance

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning javaScript and there are still many doubts. I've already tried to search this one but maybe I am using the wrong words. I am always delaying this but since the size of the project I am working on is becoming larger than I expected I need to be clarified.

I am aware that are costs in terms of speed in both **searching up the scope** and **accessing the Dom**. But I don't know which one is slower than the other.

Is it faster...

**a)** to go up the scope chain to grab the variable with the jQuery object, **but** go to the Dom just once

or

**b)** Not go up the scope chain, **but** go to the Dom again

```
var $el = $("#el");

//$el is used on this scope (and so, the question makes some sense:))

$el (...)

// some or lot's of code

function a() {

   // some or lot's of code

   function b(){

      // some or lot's of code

      function c() {

         a) $el (...)
         b) var $el = $("#el");
            $el (...)

      }

  }

}
```

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking, or what the concern is here. It may be better if you could give a real-world example instead of this extracted logic.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, but in general: Accessing variables is fast, calling functions to search for something in the DOM is slow.

Comment: Assigning the DOM element to a variable once is better than doing it repeatedly.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan As this is more a theoretical question I just tried to grab the essence of the doubt. But maybe you are right.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you, but let's say I have 100 variables accessing the DOM. I could define all of them in the first scope? I.e Use only the first scope to access the DOM. Is it a good practice? It's what I am doing but I never see code written in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option A is faster. (Declaring the variable on top)

When you need `$("#el")` more then once store it as a variable. Using the DOM multiple times is slow.

Greg Franko explains a few best practices [here](http://gregfranko.com/jquery-best-practices/#/10). See slide 10-13 for your question.

Comment: Thank you:) Just to get rid of all doubts. Let's say I have 100 variables that access the DOM. I could use the 1st scope to define all those 'DOM variables' beforehand and then access always those variables inside all the functions? Is it a good practice?

Comment: Yes, when accessing an DOM element more then 1 time you should declare a variable for it.

Answer (score 1):

While your question is very unclear, perhaps I can answer it with a general rule of thumb:

The DOM is slowwwww. If you can avoid traversing it, do so. If you search the DOM to find a specfic node, store that reference in a variable to avoid having to search through the DOM again.

Comment: Thank you:) Just to get rid of all doubts. I could use the 1st scope to access the DOM, imagine, define all the DOM variables beforehand and then access always those variables inside all the functions? Is it a good practice?

Comment: In theory, but it's unlikely that it will work like that. You will often be manipulating the DOM, so certain elements may not exist yet or you may remove elements that you were storing references to. If you're looking to optimize, only get what you need. If you need to access an element multiple times, store a reference to it in a variable. Also note that it's usually not good to have global variables, so getting all of your elements beforehand has its tradeoffs

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations:) They will be a kind of guide for me.

Answer (score 1):

If I understanded your question, you are asking about performance accessing elements in jQuery. Here you have some tips:

- Every time you have to get the reference to a jQuery object ($("#el") in your example) has a operational cost. In terms of performance, you should always try to declare the minimun necessary elements to your needs.
- Accessing siblings (siblings()), parents (closest(), parent()) or children (children(), find()) is a good option if is just for a few operations, but if you are going to use that elements many times, its better reference them with a direct selector like $("#el-child") or ("#el .child").
- If you declare a var like $el = $("#el") you get a reference of the node in its current state. Sometimes this node has being updated, removed, re-created, or something else, and this reference wont keep trak of them, so you have to call this $el = $("#el") again so, as I said before, it depends how your website logic works.

Note: sorry about my english, I know it's not good at all hehe

Comment: Thank you:) Your third point is very important . I am aware of it. To get rid of all my doubts, using your recommendations, going to the DOM few times as possible and using previous accesses to create new variables, let's say I have 100 variables that grab elements from the DOM. In that case I could define all of them in the first scope and then inside the functions access those variables without going to the DOM again. Is it a good practice? In my project I am doing so, I go to the DOM only in the first scope but the list of variables is becoming huge and I've never seen code like that:)

Comment: if i have to access 100 elements, i'd make something like define as null, and the frist time you access it define it (you can do a function to check and assign to a argument like `$el = checkAndAssign($el,'selector'); `being the function something like: `function checkAndAssign(var, selector){ return var !== null ? var : $('selector')}})` But as i said, you have to be carefull if reference is being updated ;)